# Imprimi [object HTMLInputElement]

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Quando monto a minha tabela dinamicamente apenas meu primeiro elemento é montado corretamente.Os outros imprimem um dado estranho [object HTMLInputElement]

**index**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Produto

```
<h1 class="text-center">Cadastro Produto</h1>

<form class="form" onsubmit="produtoController.adicionar(event)">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="nome">Nome</label>
        <input type="text" id="nome" class="form-control" required autofocus/>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="quantidade">Quantidade</label>
        <input type="number" min="1" step="1" id="quantidade" class="form-control" value="1" required/>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="valor">Valor</label>
        <input id="valor" type="number" class="form-control" min="0.01" step="0.01" value="0.0" required />
    </div>


    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Salvar</button>
</form>

<br>
<br>
<div id="produtoView"></div>


<script src="js/app/model/Produto.js"></script>
<script src="js/app/controller/ProdutoController.js"></script>
<script src="js/app/model/ListaProdutos.js"></script>
<script src="js/app/view/View.js"></script>
<script src="js/app/view/ProdutoView.js"></script>

<script>
    let produtoController = new ProdutoController()
</script>
```

**ListaProdutos**

```
class ListaProdutos {
constructor() {
    this._produtos = [];
}

adiciona(produto) {
    this._produtos.push(produto);
}
get produtos() {
    return [].concat(this._produtos)
}
```

**Produto**

```
class Produto {
constructor(nome, quantidade, valor) {
    this._nome = nome;
    this._quantidade = quantidade;
    this._valor = valor;

}
get nome() {
    return this._nome;
}

get quantidade() {
    return this._quantidade = quantidade;
}

get valor() {
    return this._valor = valor;
}
```

}

}

**View**

```
class View {
constructor(elemento) {
    this._elemento = elemento;
}

template() {
    throw new Error("O metodo template deve ser implementado");
}


update(model) {
    this._elemento.innerHTML = this.template(model);
}
```

}

**ProdutoView**

```
class ProdutoView extends View {
constructor(elemento) {
    super(elemento);
}
template(model) {
        return `
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>NOME</th>
            <th>QUANTIDADE</th>
            <th>VALOR</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
  <tbody>
        ${model.produtos.map(p => `

    <tr> 
        <td>${p.nome}</td>
        <td>${p.quantidade}</td>
        <td>${p.valor}</td>

    </tr>
    `)}
    </tbody>

    <tfoot>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

`;
    }

}

**ProdutoController**

```
class ProdutoController {
constructor() {
        // VALORES EXTRAIDOS DOS FORMULARIOS
        let $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);
        this._inputNome = $('#nome');
        this._inputQuantidade = $('#quantidade');
        this._inputValor = $('#valor');
        //INSTANCIAR A LISTA
        this._listaProdutos = new ListaProdutos();
        //INSTANCIAR A VIEWS
        this._produtoView = new ProdutoView($('#produtoView'));
        this._produtoView.update(this._listaProdutos);
    }
 //EVENTOS
adicionar(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this._listaProdutos.adiciona(this._criaProduto());
    this._produtoView.update(this._listaProdutos);
    this._limparFormulario();

}

_criaProduto() {
    return new Produto(this._inputNome.value, this._inputQuantidade.value, this._inputValor.value);
}
_limparFormulario() {
    this._inputNome.value = '';
    this._inputQuantidade.value = 1;
    this._inputValor.value = 0;
    this._inputNome.focus();
}
```

}

**IMPRESSÃO COM ERRO**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Perceba que no controller você está capturando o elemento em si, não seu valor: `this._inputValor = $('#valor')`. Se quer o valor, precisa obter o valor do elemento com o `.value` ou `.val()`, dependendo de como fazer.

Comment: Realmente me esqueci de colocar o .value .Corrigido mas o Erro persiste..

Comment: Esse é todo o código?

Comment: não,tem o html e o model,achei que o erro não estava nesta parte e por não poluir a pergunta não postei mas vou postar o restante

Comment: O HTML não precisa postar.

Comment: Foi postado o código que não foi colocado para analise.

Comment: Quando vc clica em salvar essa tabelinha é atualizada, pegando os valores do formulário, é isso?

Comment: Aqui, por exemplo: `this._inputQuantidade = $('#quantidade');` me parece que falta um `.val()`

Comment: Isso,a ideia é pegar os valores do formulário  no ProdutoController capturando os valores em seu construtor ,por ser uma classe do tipo controller precisamos instanciar as views e as listas que utilizamos.Após instanciar a ProdutoView recebo por parâmetro o id(produtoView )da minha div que eu acrescentei no html para gerar a tabela dinamicamente,como tu falastes a tabela é atualizada conforme forinserindo .Acredito que deu +- pra passar a ideia.

Comment: ` this._inputQuantidade = $('#quantidade');` não necessita do .value ,por que tipo ele está recebendo do formulário apenas para poder alimentar nosso objeto produto,que no mesmo declaramos o .value.

Comment: Eu não sou muito inteirado nessa sintaxe. Tenta `${p.quantidade.value}`, já que está retornando o elemento.

Comment: Funcionou dvd ,seguindo tua sugestão coloquei .value nos elementos que não é o  nome e funfou ,posta a resposta que eu coloco como solucionada,valeu pela força!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já que está retornando o próprio elemento, você pode pegar o valor adicionando `.value` em:

`{p.quantidade.value}` e `${p.valor.value}`